# Does DCE have its own linux kernel stack or does it use the host machine's linux kernel stack?

Tags: linux-kernel, ns-3

I have installed DCE (Directed Code Execution in advance mode). My question here is, when they say DCE uses the linux kernel stack, does DCE have its own linux kernel stack or does it use the host machine's linux kernel stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DCE will not use the host linux kernel network stack. DCE will use the network stack from a specific version of the linux kernel that is coming from a separate ns-3 module named net-next-sim. For example, in the last version (1.8) released of dce, this module is being pulled from the "sim-ns3-2.6.36-branch" branch of the git repo https://github.com/direct-code-execution/net-next-sim.git .

In practice, you do not have to worry about where this is coming from since bake will automatically download, build, install, and configure it for you if you enable this feature. As suggested in the manual (https://www.nsnam.org/docs/dce/manual/html/getting-started.html), it's a matter of:

```
mkdir dce
cd dce
bake.py configure -e dce-linux-1.8
bake.py download
bake.py build
```

Comment: Thanks. So, now when I want to run a user space application (it can be anything, for now I am trying iperf) using the MPTCP protocol, the changes will be made in the DCE kernel and not the host linux kernel stack? And after making these changes, I need to recompile the kernel and it should work. Am I right?

Comment: yes. Just make sure that the simulation script you write actually asks dce to use the linux network stack because by default, it will use the ns-3 network stack instead. i.e., if you are trying to run the iperf example from the quick start guide, ./waf --run "dce-iperf --stack=linux"

Answer (score 0):

DCE is just a module for ns-3 that provides facilities to execute existing implementations of kernel network protocols, so as described in the DCE documentation it uses the installed linux kernel.